# Quiero crear un conversor

Tags: edittext

Tengo este codigo con el cual quiero hacer un conversor, en este tengo 3 EditText y lo que quiero es poder ingresar datos en celsius y que automaticamente me convierta los farenheit y kelvin, y tambien quiero poder ingresar datos en farenheit y que automaticamente se conviertan los celsius y los kelvin, y asi mismo para los kelvin.

En si lo que quiero hacer es que los EditText pueda ingresar datos y tambien mostrar datos al mismo tiempo. agradezco su apoyo aun soy un principiante.

```
<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:text="Conversor de temperatura"
    android:textSize="30dp"
    android:textAlignment="center"
    android:layout_margin="10dp"/>

<EditText
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="celsius"
    android:textAlignment="center"/>

<EditText
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="fahrenheit"
    android:textAlignment="center"/>

<EditText
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="kelvin" 
    android:textAlignment="center"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

primero que nada tienes que empezar dandoles sus respectivos ID a cada `EditText`despues de esto, tienes que empezar a configurar tu activity en java, que se encuentra en app->Java->`NombreDelPaquete` estando ahi, encontraras un archivo donde ingresarás todo el codigo, en el metodo que encuentras y se llama `onCreate` como sugerencia puedes crear un metodo en este caso le llamaré `conversor` en el cual definiremos como van a actuar cada uno de tus `EditText`

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_inicio);
    conversor();
}


void conversor(){
    final EditText editText1 =findViewById(R.id.Edit_Publicacion);//en lugar de Edit_Publicaciónn ingresas el ID de su respectivo EditText
    final EditText editText2 =findViewById(R.id.Edit_Publicacion);//en lugar de Edit_Publicaciónn ingresas el ID de su respectivo EditText
    final EditText editText3 =findViewById(R.id.Edit_Publicacion);//en lugar de Edit_Publicaciónn ingresas el ID de su respectivo EditText

    editText1.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {
            //despues de que finalice de editar el texto obtenemos el valor de cada EditText y lo modificamos
            //pasarlo de celsius a la conversión que tu quieras, aquí usas tus formulas
            editText2.setText(Integer.parseInt(editText1.getText().toString())*200/1000);
            editText3.setText(Integer.parseInt(editText1.getText().toString())*200/1000);
        }
    });

    editText2.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {
            //despues de que finalice de editar el texto obtenemos el valor de cada EditText y lo modificamos
            //pasarlo de celsius a la conversión que tu quieras, aquí usas tus formulas
            editText1.setText(Integer.parseInt(editText2.getText().toString())*200/1000);
            editText3.setText(Integer.parseInt(editText2.getText().toString())*200/1000);
        }
    });
    editText3.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {
            //despues de que finalice de editar el texto obtenemos el valor de cada EditText y lo modificamos
            //pasarlo de celsius a la conversión que tu quieras, aquí usas tus formulas
            editText2.setText(Integer.parseInt(editText3.getText().toString())*200/1000);
            editText1.setText(Integer.parseInt(editText3.getText().toString())*200/1000);
        }
    });


}
```

Se repiten 3 veces pues tienes que tener 3 eventos por cada `EditText` por cada uno

[Fuente que te puede ayudar a entender el funcionamiento de addTextChangedListener](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8063439/android-edittext-finished-typing-event)

Comment: Recuerda tener cuidado al ingresar letras o simbolos dado que tienes que checar las excepciones que te puede arrojar, algo rapido y espero te sirva de ayuda

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu pronta respuesta, voy a proceder a editarlo.